# A Div with images which is scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to make a div which have a lot of images which takes 85% width of the screen. the height doesn't matter as long as the content stays the same. the footer is fixed and the navigation will drop down a div which contains images at the width (85%) of the content size. and the images should scroll with two buttons, next and previous. i'm new to java, html and Css. please help me. thank you :)

Comment: Do you have any code to present at all? And have you tried Google?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Hint: I think you wanted to say javascript, which is not the same as java.

Comment: yes i have tried google and every possible website. and finally ended up here. please help

Comment: SO is here to help you with issues you have with your code, not to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I will help you on your way.

I hope this helps you!

To get a div to get scrollable you have to specify that in your css code with the `overflow` attribute.

Take a look in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/d8dFd/